# How to access UINavigationController in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have created a View where the NavigationBar comes from Obj-c(Native code) and the rest of the view comes from React Native.

Now in the react native view, i have a link which should show the content in a new screen with the navigation experience. I am able to show the content but unable to find a way to change navBar title and show back button on the navBar.

Can you please let me know how we can get access to NavigationBar(Obj-c) in ReactNative?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe React Native supports this.  You cannot take an object created in one language and access it in another.  It would be a better idea to create your navigation bar in your JS and use it throughout your app.  That even allows you to propagate that UI to your android apps.